# Searchview after rotation - Button goes to the "3 dots"

Tags: android, xml, rotation, searchview

I'm having a bad time with my Searchview on Android dev.

I'm trying to implement the Searchview on my toolbar's app. For now it's working very well but when I rotate the device, the search view behaves strangely.

My objective is persist the query text, so on "OnCreateOptionsMenu"

```java
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_funcionarios_toolbar, menu);

    clearSearchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.botao_limpar_busca);

    searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.botao_buscar);
    searchItem.setIcon(new IconicsDrawable(getContext(), MaterialDesignIconic.Icon.gmi_search).sizeDp(24));

    searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

    searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(searchViewTextListener);


    searchView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!mQuery.equals("")) {
                searchView.setQuery(mQuery,false);
            }
        }
    });

    if (mQuery != null & !mQuery.equals("")) {
        searchItem.expandActionView();
    }
}
```

But If I use .expandActionView(), after the rotation (and cleaning the field using the "X" button provided by the SearchView), the MenuItem turns into those 3 little dots without any action. To restore the previous behaviour, I have to rotate the device again.

I'm almost sure the problem is on my XML:

```
<item
android:id="@+id/botao_buscar"
android:title="@string/menu_buscar"
app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
```

Changing the "showAsAction" attribute to "always" worked like a charm.

Any thoughts on this ?

Comment: Same problem. But showAsAction="always" will display an ugly fullscreen search bar though... after rotation

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @vihkat unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 4):

**Finally**, I found a solution in this site: [LINK](https://thedeveloperworldisyours.com/android/to-restore-searchview-state/). (Thank you so much for this post.)

I copy the code here because It's could be a dependency.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_main_action_search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:title="@string/menu_main_search_title"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" />
```

Code:

```
searchMenuItem.expandActionView();
mSearchView.setQuery(mSearchString, true);
mSearchView.clearFocus();
```

Finally the 3 dot not appear again. There is a search icon !! awesome

Comment: I spent about 3 hours to find this solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem and solved it like this.

In onCreateOptionsMenu:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.search_option);

    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(searchQueryListener);

    if(searchQuery!=null && !searchQuery.equals("")) {
        searchView.setIconified(false);
        searchView.setQuery(searchQuery,true);
        searchView.clearFocus();
    }

}
```

For the searchView menu item:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/search_option"
    android:title="@string/button_search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

In my case I have another menu item with icon to the right of the search view and this way it works fine when rotating the device.

Answer (score 1):

To overcome the ugly search bar resulting from `showAsAction="always"`, I solved this way (keeping `showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"`):

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {        

    ...

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(mQuery))
        new Handler().post(() -> {
            searchView.clearFocus();
            searchView.setIconified(false);
            searchItem.expandActionView();//or MenuItemCompat.expandActionView for older devices
            searchView.setQuery(mQuery, false);//or true here if you want it submitted!
        });

}
```

The trick is to call `searchItem.expandActionView()` after `searchView.setIconfied(false)`.

For increased stability, I keep the whole sequence in a `post` - as you did - but it looks like is working better to have a `new Handler()` to do it.

Comment: Same. 3 dot is there